# What is the advantage of Mapbox-gl native vs. javascript on mobile devices?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

[Mapbox-gl](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl/) renders maps from vector tiles locally on the clients device. You can either use the js library or use the native c++ bindings (for ios/android/etc.) For a mobile device, what would be the practical advantages of using the native bindings? The javascript library seems much simpler.